# How to stop a loop on arduino

Tags: arduino

Im trying to make a code that turn on a led when infrared detected, but when a loop is started and I want to change it to another loop but it doesnt work

```
#include <IRremote.h>
int receptor = 7;
int led = 2;
IRrecv irrecv(receptor);
decode_results codigo; //OBJETO CODIGO DE CLASE decode_result, oriundo de IRremote.h

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // INICIA LA RECEPCIÓN
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&codigo))
  {
    Serial.println(codigo.value, HEX);

    if (codigo.value == 0xFF6897) //CÓDIGO DEL NÚMERO CERO PARA ACTIVAR LED
    {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    }

    if (codigo.value == 0xFF30CF) //CÓDIGO DEL NÚMERO UNO PARA DESACTIVAR LED
    { 
      loop();
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }

    delay(500);
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `loop()` function inside of itself (or better, you "can" in the sense that it's possible, but it's not what you want to do I guess).

Comment: If `codigo.value == 0xFF30CF`, then `loop()` is called recursively, without receiving a new value. I don't know the details of `irrecv.decode()`, but either it will evaluate to true again, resulting in infinite recursion and eventually a stack overflow, or it returns false, and it can never return true again, because you didn't `resume` the receiver.

Comment: and how i fix it?

Comment: What happens if you just remove the `loop()` call after `if (... 0xFF30CF)`?

Comment: it just do it once

Comment: You don't need to call `loop()`, it is called by itself. So the truth is that the `loop()` function is automatically called repeatedly, but if you call it inside itself (as your original code is), the calls become _recursive_, you never go out of it, like @tttapa said some comments above.

Comment: Without `loop()` the led keep on after 1 second off

Comment: Yes, that's what you told it to do.  Turn off, wait one second, turn on, wait one second, wait another half a second, then clear the command and look for another.  If you want it to keep blinking that until you give another command then you need another variable to keep up with the last command you received.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goal correctly - you could simply split the void loop into 2 sections, wherefrom you disable and enable your sections by an if-function checking a boolean. So if the boolean is true it is running the first function and otherwise the second.
I hope this one works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want recursion in your code (calling loop() inside the loop function).
While not familiar with the adruino, I think I know enough C to fix your code.

```
int blinkingState = 0; // should probably be an enum.

void loop()
{
  irrecv.decode(&codigo); // decode into codigo
  if (codigo != NULL) // null reference check
  {
    Serial.println(codigo.value, HEX);
    // Case 1: always on
    if (codigo.value == 0xFF6897) //CÓDIGO DEL NÚMERO CERO PARA ACTIVAR LED
    {
      blinkingState = 0;
    }
    // Case 2: blinking, made else if to get some more speed and skip a second check if case 1 is true.
    else if (codigo.value == 0xFF30CF) //CÓDIGO DEL NÚMERO UNO PARA DESACTIVAR LED
    {
      blinkingState = 1;
    }
  }
  // blink or don't blink according to global variable.
  if (blinkingState == 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(500); // moved from end of function to here otherwise case 2 will blink irregularly
  }
  else if (blinkingState = 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
  }
  irrecv.resume();
}
```

this assumes loop is called repeatedly from outside and doesn't need an actual loop inside of it.

You should not use recursion for potentially long running loops. in fact you should avoid it where it isn't too much trouble to do so. calling a function creates a new stackframe. and stack is very limited to 1MB on most systems.

Recursion can be useful for certain problems, but 99.99% of the time you don't want this.